# How to determine which serialization to use in kafka producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

while going through kafka documentation,I found many types of serialization in kafka producer but I am confused about how to determine the serialization for any use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you know the role of Serialization that might help, So the way Kafka works is by looking at any message in terms of Byte array (byte[]). Kafka never opens your message to figure out if its int or double or string, instead it assumes that your sending byte[].

But to make development easy for producer and consumer Kafka has defined Serializer and Deserializer Interface and they work in pair. So if you know that you want to publish Integer as message use IntegerSerializer which converts it to byte[] and hands over to kafka on the consumer you know the message is serialized using IntegerSerializer so you use IntegerDeserializer. Same way if you have custom java object, then you will have to figure out a way (Default java or Kyro serializer) to convert java object into byte[] in producer and corresponding Deserializer to convert the byte[] back to your java object.

Hope that helps